# How to create an array of merged items from 2 corresponding items, each from another additional array, using (mainly) array methods?

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, mapping, reduce

I've converted CSV based text files to arrays containing headers and rows, and now I want to convert them into the below given solution. Can anybody do this using methods like `map`, `reduce` or whatever.

The arrays I have are:

```
let header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];
```

The result I want is:

```
[{
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
  d: 4,
}, {
  a: 5,
  b: 6,
  c: 7,
  d: 8,
}, {
  a: 9,
  b: 0,
  c: 1,
  d: 2,
}]
```

I was able to do this using for loop but that wasn't the appropriate solution for es6.

Above I've mentioned some dummy arrays, right now the actual code is:

```
const recordReader = content => {
  let weatherRecords = [];
  let rows = content.split('\n');
  let headers = rows.shift().split(',');

  for (let row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
    let weatherReading = {};
    if (!rows[row]) {
      continue;
    }
    let record = rows[row].split(',');
  
    for (let column = 0; column < headers.length; column++) {
      weatherReading[headers[column]] = record[column];
    }
    weatherRecords.push(weatherReading);
  }
  return weatherRecords;
};
```

Comment: Are you able to show the `.map()` approach that you tried and didn't work?

Comment: @NickParsons I've mentioned the  current code at the end of question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could map the rows and reduce the row into an object:

```js
const header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];

const result = rows.map((row) =>
  row.split(',').reduce(
    (obj, cell, i) => ({
      ...obj,
      [header[i]]: Number(cell),
    }),
    {}
  )
);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

with a combination of map and reduce:

```js
const header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];

const res = rows.map(row => {
  const columns = row.split(',');
  return columns.reduce( (acc,cur,i) => ({...acc,[header[i]]:cur}) , {})
  }
);

console.log(res);
```

This admits a one-liner but i reckon is not very clear to see what it does:

```js
const header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];

const res = rows.map(row => row.split(',').reduce( (acc,cur,i) => ({...acc,[header[i]]:cur}) , {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) your `rows` elements to objects. To create the object, you can grab the string of numbers, and split them into an array, which you then use `.map()` on to grab the number values and the associated header from `headers` using the index of the current number (`i`). By putting these into a `[key, value]` pair array, you can call [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) on it to build your object. The below also uses the [unary plus operator (`+`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to convert your string digit to a number:

```js
const header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];

const res = rows.map(item =>
  Object.fromEntries(item.split(',').map((n, i) => [header[i], +n]))
);

console.log(res);
```

Note, the above uses `Object.fromEntries()` which was introduced after ES6, you can use `Object.assign()` for a smilar approach, which is ES6:

```js
const header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];

const res = rows.map(item =>
  Object.assign({}, ...item.split(',').map((n, i) => ({[header[i]]: +n})))
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: @NickParsons Isn't this solution too expensive with a time complexity of `O(n^4)` ?

Comment: @FahadAshraf It depends on what `n` is? We have three arrays, `rows` is of size `n` and `headers` is of size `k`, and then the inner split array needs to have equal elements to that in headers, so that is also `k`. So we have two lengths `n` and `k`. The outer `.map()` is `n` iterations, and for each iteration, we do `k` iterations with the inner `.map()`. So it is `O(n*k)`.

Comment: @FahadAshraf In total, outer map is `n` iterations and the inner split, inner map and inner fromEntries call is `k` iterations, these all happen indepdently for each iteration of the map function, so its k+k+k, or 3k (_not_ k\*k\*k or k^3), which when looking at big-oh is `O(nk)`. On the other hand, the reduce options shown here using `{...curr/obj, }` are `O(n*(k^2))`, as the object spread `...curr` adds additional iterations, which when summed with inner `.reduce()` call is `k^2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
let header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
let rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];

let result = rows.map((x) => {
    let elementArr = x.split(',');
    let response = [];
    header.forEach((item,i) => {
        response[item] = parseInt(elementArr[i])
    });
    
    return {...response};
});
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 let header = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
 let rows = ['1,2,3,4', '5,6,7,8', '9,0,1,2'];
 result=[]
rows.forEach(e=>{
    let a={};
     let i=0;
header.forEach((h)=>{
    a[h]=e.split(',')[i++]
 });
  result.push(a)
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

A nested [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) based approach will do the job.

One iterates the `rows`-array with the outer reducer-function which again iterates each column-value (derived from each [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)ted `row`) by a second `reduce`-task which assigns a column-value to a column-key where each key is derived from the additionally passed `header`-array and the current inner iteration's column-index.

```js
function rowwiseAssignColumValuesToHeaderColumnKeys({ header, result }, row) {
  result
    .push(
      row
        .split(',')
        .reduce((rowItem, columnValue, columnIndex) =>
          Object.assign(rowItem, {

            [ header[columnIndex] ]: Number(columnValue.trim())

          }), {} // to be aggregated `rowItem` passed as initial value.
        )
    );
  return { header, result };
}
console.log(
  ['1,2,3,4', '5, 6, 7, 8', '9,0,1,2']
    .reduce(
      rowwiseAssignColumValuesToHeaderColumnKeys, {
        header: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        result: [],
      },
    ).result
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The above mainly `reduce` based approach can be refactored into a re-usable mapping function which takes [the 2nd `thisArg` parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters) of [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) into account

```js
function assignColumValuesAccordingToBoundHeaderColumnKeys(row) {
  const header = this;
  return  row
    .split(',')
    .reduce((rowItem, columnValue, columnIndex) =>
      Object.assign(rowItem, {

        [ header[columnIndex] ]: Number(columnValue.trim())

      }), {} // to be aggregated `rowItem` passed as initial value.
    );
}
console.log(
  ['1,2,3,4', '5, 6, 7, 8', '9,0,1,2']
    .map(
      assignColumValuesAccordingToBoundHeaderColumnKeys,
      ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
    )
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```